# Setting up raid hardware with out deleting data

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

so I have a home lab, and in the beginning, I started with only 1 DISK, and in the raid config, I bypassed the raid because I didn't have 2 disks to make a RAID 10 or 1, but now, I want some redundancy, and I want to install a new identical disk. My problem is that even though I know how to set up a raid in the BIOS, if I create a new one, it will wipe the disk and all my data, and I was wondering if it was possible to make a new raid 1 but without losing the data.

My server is a HP Proliant DL380 G8 server.

Would rebuild work or would i need to use a different method?

Comment: I think you talk about the Smartarray, not software RAID. Check the [ssacli manual](https://community.hpe.com/hpeb/attachments/hpeb/itrc-264/148204/3/HP%20Smart%20Storage%20Administrator%20User%20Guide.pdf#page63); I am sure that you can convert your setup to RAID1.

Comment: Check the manual for "migrate" not "rebuild" - the latter is for replacing a failed drive.